# Problem with proc report multilayered heading

Tags: sas, proc-report

I am trying to create a report that looks like:
[image]

The first row is in the column named `MPM_Description`.
The second row is the Release date of those movies and the third row is the box office collection. The column to the left is the accounts name. The table is filled with the `POS`(point of sale) value for each movie titles.

The input data is like this:
[image]

I tried using proc report but could not succeed. I even saw some papers dicussing about the columns in `Proc report` but I am not sure which column to in order to get the desired output.
I am really looking for the answer.

Thank you,

Shankar

Comment: There are ways. I'm going to assume your question is not 'is this possible' because the answer is yes, but 'how do I create a report like this'. If that's correct please post sample data that reflects what you've shown and any attempt you've tried so far per SO rules [ask]. Otherwise, if your question is this possible, then it's answered.

Comment: I tried to add the data there but I could not. So, I edited the post with the output and the input data. The only thing I am not getting is how to put the Original_Street_Date and new_box lined under the MPM_Description creating one column for each title.-Shankar

Comment: Instructions on adding data is here, but you do have to show an attempt as well. You can try communities.sas.com but the first request will be for sample data as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125348/how-to-convert-a-sas-data-set-to-a-data-step/53125972#53125972